# How to change TextView Value in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to change TextView value in Fragment but it not clearing old value.

Value is overlapping on old value.

[image]

**Code from Fragment -**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

TextView t1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    t1 = view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    t1.setText(s1);

    return view;
}
}
```

**Code from Activity -**

```
public static String s1;
@Override
public void onOptionClicked(int position, Object objectClicked) {
    // Set the toolbar title
    setTitle(mTitles.get(position));

    // Set the right options selected
    mMenuAdapter.setViewSelected(position, true);
    s1 = mTitles.get(position);
    // Navigate to the right fragment
    switch (position) {
        default:
            goToFragment(new MainFragment(), false);
            break;
    }
    // Close the drawer
    mViewHolder.mDuoDrawerLayout.closeDrawer();
}
```

**Fragment xml file -**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tried by using below code but not working....

```
public void setText(String text){
        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        textView.setText(textview1);
    }
```

Please help.... Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Seems like you have two overlapping fragments.

Comment: can you put that code where you are adding fragments?

Comment: Which kind of fragment are you using in this case? Seems you are having overlapping fragments, or overlapping views on your fragment. Could you please share more of your fragment code to help u help you.

Comment: What kind fragment are you using?

Comment: Could you be having duplicate layot files in your application? Please check.

Comment: You are creating a new fragment and not replacing the old one, that's why you have overlapping fragments

Comment: @Ranjan do you know how to close old one?

Comment: You should use a fragment container in activity layout and use `supportFragmentManager` to `replace` fragment inside that container. But it actually depends upon UI as well whether you actually want to show 2 different fragments in single activity. Read here how to manage fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Managing

Comment: thank you... one more question...my current implementation is correct or not? I mean does it take more memory, because i am creating new fragment every time...

Comment: It definitely is not the correct way and it takes tiny bit of memory but its ok, phone have lots of memory these days. It's a drop in the ocean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `.add` in your `goToFragment()` code, then you should replace with `.replace`

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container,
             currentFragment).commit()
```

to

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
             currentFragment).commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code in onCreateView method of your fragment and it will remove this overlapping issue

```
View    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: This is just a `Jugaad`.

Answer (score 0):

fragment.xml add (android:background="@color/white") in your Layout.

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"      
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ranjan said it is not good practice, why do not you create `MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();` inside onCreate() and use that in that method. In this way you will have only one instance. I do not use fragments like this so I do not have good idea about your code otherwise.